Como puedo sacar el id de un item de mercadolibre a partir del "catalog_product_id", es decir, el ID que aparece en la URL del storefront?
Estoy intentando aclimatizarme a como funcionan los metodos de API publico de mercadolibre, sin embargo me encontre con esta situacion rara.
Al usar el sitio web publico de mercadolibre para API para desarrolladores (https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/) inmediatamente despues de "items/" va el ID del producto, lo que seria MLA ("A" = Argentina) y los numeros identificadores. La respuesta en JSON es del item completo, que incluye un link directo al storefront de mercadolibre para este producto (articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-'10 numeros de ID').
Sin embargo, al entrar al link del producto, no puedo evitar notar que la URL entera cambia, y no solo en terminos de formato, si no tambien el ID a mostrar (MLA + 10 numeros), el cual es reemplazado por algo que en el JSON del item aparece como "catalog_product_id" (MLA + 8 numeros), inmediatamente seguido del "/p/" en la URL de la tienda. Mi pregunta en sí es si hay alguna forma de obtener el ID verdadero del item para los endpoints a partir de este catalog_product_id ya que este ID no sirve para hacer llamados API. Al intentarlo devuelve codigo 404.
Dejo adjuntadas imagenes para ayudar con la claridad:

Aqui se puede ver la URL del API GET para la informacion completa de este producto

Aqui esta el permalink para llegar al producto, como se puede ver, funciona con el mismo ID, pero en un formato diferente (articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-'10 numeros' el resto de la URL que queda recortada es irrelevante y no se necesita para llegar al producto en la tienda

Este es el numero de catalog_product_id, el cual aparentemente no tiene ninguna relacion con el ID del item.

Al clickear en el permalink, esta es la URL final para el producto. Aunque tecnicamente si se clickea directamente desde permalink del JSON el ID real esta al final de la URL, este no aparece si decido buscar otro producto por la pagina web. Todos los productos usan el catalog_product_id, el cual es el ID de 8 numeros.
En resumen: ¿Existe alguna forma de encontrar el ID del producto real a partir de la URL del producto?
